Не переопределяется свойство в классе
Есть три класса:
class ToDoListManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(owner=user)

# Create your models here.
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
    
    objects = ToDoListManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

(дальше в другом файле)
class ToDoListListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("account_login")
    template_name = 'tasks/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ToDoList.objects.for_user(self.request.user)

ToDoList.objects в классе ToDoListListView ссылается не на ToDoListManager, как мы переопределили в ToDoList, а на BaseManager[ToDoList], если в VS Code навести курсор на objects. Все импорты правильные. Смысла делать print(type(ToDoList.objects)) Я не вижу, потому что итак, когда я обращаюсь по урлу http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/1/, в брузере ничего не выводится. Только шаблон:
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if object_list %}
        <h3>All list</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for todo in object_list %}
                <li>
                    <div role="button" onclick="">{{ todo.title }}</div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <h3>You have't list</h3> вот это выводится, хотя список есть
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

В сеттингсах приложения вроде всё верно. Пакет должен найти, но он всё равно не хочет видеть.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

Если нужно, вот структура:
├── manage.py
├── tasks
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_create_task_models.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── todo
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py здесь и прописан BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── users
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_craete_user_admin_models.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py

Что делать?
